# Automate adding RSS content to HTML then pull HTML from URL and send out via email program

Tags: wordpress, email, automation, rss, mailchimp

I have a blog and I would like to send out a daily email with all the new blog posts.

I am using a custom HTML email template. It is hosted on a webpage.

I have an automation to pull the HTML from my URL every day at 2PM.

I would like to pull in the RSS feed and plug it into my HTML automatically.

This way, as soon as a new blog is updated, the email is updated. When the daily email goes out, it has all of the content posted in the past 24 hours.

Other Notes: I am using mail chimp for now (free sending) until we grow and switch to Paramount.

Pulling in HTML via URL

Would like to include the featured image from the blog if possible. The image will be 1200x629 from the blog. It is a large file size, but I can re-scale via height="" etc...

Yes, Mailchimp has a template for this. It doesn't look very good though. The format they use really doesn't pop teh way I want it to.

Comment: Revising your question will make it easier to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is that a question or request? **We are here to help in your code**, if you haven't tried anything then we cant help much. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a question.